# Square root of matrix over $F_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-fields, diagonalization

Let $M \in F_p^{n\times n}$ be a square matrix of dimension $n\times n$ with entries over $F_p$.

Then we want to obtain $M$ from $M^2=M\cdot M$. Initially I think of the old diagonalisation procedure of solving the square root of a matrix by:

$$M^2 = P\cdot D \cdot P^{-1}$$

$$M = P\cdot D^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot P^{-1}$$

Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues as entries defined over $F_p$. So $2^{-1} \pmod p$ must be a unit on $F_p^{*}$, this is $2$ must be an unit on $F_p^{*}$ so it has an inverse.

Moreover, when taking $F_2$ as the field, the diagonalisation method doesn't yield the square root matrix as $2$ is not an unit on $F_2^{*}$.

I know that if $M^k \in GL(n,F_2)$ then $\gcd(k,\vert GL(n,F_2) \vert)$ must be equal to $1$ so $M^{k\cdot d}=M$ where $d$ is the multiplicative inverse of $k$ modulo the order of the given general linear group. It works also with the multiplicative order of $M$ in $GL$.

But what if $k=2$ and the field is $F_2$? Is there any method for computing the square root matrix of $M^2$ over $F_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

You already start with a rather strong assumption, that your matrix $M^2$ can be diagonalized. That is wrong in general and only true for some matrices.

But let's assume that you can write
$$M^2 = PDP^{-1}.$$

Then every diagonal entry of $D$ is either $0$ or $1$, and both of these have unique square roots. In fact, you get $D^{1/2} = D$ and thus $M = M^2$.
That is, of course, a boring case, but once again shows that your assumption that $M$ is diagonizable is already very restrictive; in the case of the binary field, it means that $M^k = M$ for all powers $k$.

In general it seems you are slightly confused with some things. To be able to get a unique $k$-th root, you need that the map
$$f : \mathbb{F}_p \to \mathbb{F}_p, x \mapsto x^k$$
is a bijection. This is equivalent to saying that the equation $x^k = 1$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$. According to this answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58359/109932), that is equivalent to $gcd(k,p-1) = 1$. That means that you can take unique square roots only over $\mathbb{F}_2$, over all other finite prime fields there are elements that do not have a square root.

So it turns out that the case of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the easy one here, if you assume that such a matrix $D$ exists.
For very general $M$ it seems finding a root is [NP complete](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397504004165), so I don't think you will find an efficient way to do it.

Comment: "You already start with a rather strong assumption, that your matrix can be diagonalized" Well $M^2$ is a matrix from the general linear group of dimension $n$ and binary coefficients. It's assumed to be non-singular so it has a diagonalisation.

"In general it seems you are slightly confused with some things. To be able to get a unique  -th root, you need that the map $f$ is a bijection" Thanks for pointing that, I can recall that argument now and it clearly trivialises the case when the field is selected to be $F_2$ as you mention. Accepted answer.

Comment: By the way I'm mistaken on the diagonalisation part, seems like I mixed some concepts. Diagonalising over $F_p$ requires that the diagonal matrix has at least $n$ eigenvalues counting multiplicities so the characteristic polynomial of $M$ should have $n$ roots over $F_p$. Applying the theory from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{F_p}$ confused me here.

Comment: To the OP. I just read your post. I don't agree with your assertion "For very general M it seems finding a root is NP complete". To find the square roots of $A\in M_n(F_2)$ (for example) is essentially equivalent to find the roots of $\chi_A$. By Berlekamp's algorithm, we can effectively factor $\chi_A$ in irreducible; each irreducible $p(x)$ has a  cyclic Galois group (because the roots are in the form $a,a^2,a^4,\cdots$); then the associated algebraic extension is given by the quotient $F_2[x]/p(x)$ where $a=x$ (cf. my post).  -To be continued-

Comment: Such an extension contains all the roots of irreducible polynomials with same degree as $p$. If in the decomposition of $\chi_A$, there are two irreducible $p,q$ with same degree, then we choose the extension $F_2[x]/p(x)$; in a second time, we can calculate the roots of $q$ as algebraic functions of $a$ -one of the roots of $p$-.

Comment: Part 3. Yet, I have a doubt. It is possible that wishing to find ALL the square roots, we are facing a system that we cannot solve in polynomial time when $n$ is large; This is the case when we want to solve a general system of $n$ quadratic equations in $n$ unknowns in $F_2$; this problem is known in cryptography. If I have some time, then I'll read your above reference.

Answer (score 2):

As Dirk wrote , your post is very unclear.

We study the following

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Let $A\in M_n(F_2)$; what are the solutions $R\in M_n(L)$ (if they exist) of the equation $R^2=A$ ? (here $L$ is an algebraic extension of $F_2$.

We consider the (unique) Chevalley-Jordan decompositions of $A,R$: $A=D+N,R=\Delta +M$ where $D,\Delta$ are diagonalizable on an extension of $F_2$ and $N,M$ are nilpotent and $DN=ND,\Delta M=M\Delta$.

$\textbf{Remark}$. Note that $D,N\in M_n(F_2)$ can be effectively calculated for every matrix $A$. The unknowns are $\Delta,M$.

Thus $R^2=\Delta^2+M^2=A=D+N$, that implies $(1)$ $\Delta^2=D$ and $(2)$ $M^2=N$.

- We give two examples for $(1)$ (there exist always solutions in $\Delta$)

i) Assume that $\chi_D(x)=p(x)=x^5+x^2+1$, a polynomial that is irreducible over $F_2$. Their roots are $a,a^2,a^4,a^8,a^{16}$ where $a\in K=F_2[x]/p(x)$, an algebraic extension of $F_2$ of degree $5$ ($a=x$ in the quotient).

Then $D=Pdiag(a,a^2,a^4,a^8,a^{16})P^{-1}$ (where $P\in GL_n(K)$) and the UNIQUE solution in $\Delta$ is $\Delta=Pdiag(a^{16},a,a^2,a^4,a^8)P^{-1}$.

EDIT. Note that $D,\Delta$ are similar. In fact, $\Delta\in M_5(F_2)$. Indeed, $D$ is similar in $M_5(F_2)$ to the companion matrix $D'=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and its square root is $\Delta'=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

More precisely $\Delta=D^{16}$ (cf. the associated eigenvalues).

ii) Note that, if $D=0$, then $\Delta=0$.

- and two examples for $(2)$ (There don't exist always solutions in $M$).

i) No solutions when $N=J_n$ (the Jordan block of dimension $n$).

ii) Let $N=diag(J_2,J_2)$. Then there are $12$ solutions in $M_4(F_2)$, including the following $4$:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}0&a&1&b\\0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&a\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.